# Remove specific elements n times in python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting

I want to remove an specific element from the list n times, if a put 7 I want to remove all sevens. I'm trying to run this code but get me an error:

```
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7]
valor = int(input('type a value: '))
for i in range(len(elements)):
    if (elements[i] == valor):
        elements.remove(valor)

print(elements)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Decrement your index (i) after removing an element.

Comment: you are changing the size of array in the loop.

Comment: use ```for i in range(len(elements)-1):```

Comment: It's much more common in Python to just make a new list with a list comprehension : `elements = [n for n in elements if n != 7]`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the list comprehension like this:

```
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7]
valor = int(input('type a value: '))
print([e for e in elements if e != valor])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove values during a for each loop.  This will work:

```
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7]
newElements = []
valor = int(input('type a value: '))
for i in elements:
    if (i != valor):
        newElements.append(i)
elements = newElements
print(elements)
```